# Adding a Local GIT Repository to a Gogs Docker Container

Tags: git, docker, gogs

I've installed Gogs using Docker.  Subsequently I have created a local repository like this (In reality the `repository` has multiple branches, etc. but I'm just keeping this example simple):

```
mkdir repository
cd repository
git init
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commmit -m "How do I get this into Gogs"
```

How do I now migrate / push this to Gogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To push changesets to gogs, you'll need to create a repo on gogs then add a remote that uses the port exposed when the container was started. If you're unsure, run the following and note the HostPort entries. Assuming the container is named gogs:

```
docker inspect  --format "{{json .HostConfig.PortBindings}}" gogs
```

The following are steps to set up an ssh remote origin.
Add your public key using the gogs web ui accessed by the HostPort entry for 3000/tcp. If you followed the gogs docker instructions, this will likely be: http://localhost:10080 If gogs is not running locally, replace localhost with the gogs hostname.

Add the following host entry to `~/.ssh/config` to more easily specify an alternate ssh port:

```
Host gogs
    # if gogs is not running locally, add the remote hostname here
    Hostname localhost
    User git
    # the following should match what is listed for HostPort 22/tcp
    port 10022
```

Test the ssh host entry with `ssh gogs`. If it works you should see:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi there, You've successfully authenticated, but Gogs does not provide shell access.
If this is unexpected, please log in with password and setup Gogs under another user.
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Add the following as your remote:

```
git remote add origin gogs:yourusername/your-repo.git
```

Note that you're replacing `git@localhost` with the `gogs` ssh host entry.

You should now be able to push to your gogs repo.

Comment: Thanks!  Had some configuration issues initially which tripped me up a bit (https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/3019), but it's all good now.  Thanks again!